# React Native and date-fns. Problem with inserting current date

Tags: javascript, react-native, date-fns

What I want to do is get variable 'todaysDate' to get todays date and make a differenceInDays and calculate weeks and days. I got the calculations to work if I enter date manually to 'todaysDate'.

I think the format of the result from ShowCurrentDate isn't ok to the date-fns. I tried to add moment.js to get today's date but it didn't work.

This is the part I would like to get working:

```
 ShowCurrentDate=()=>{

  var date = new Date().getDate();
  var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return year + ',' + month + ',' + date;
 }
```

Full code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
import { differenceInDays } from 'date-fns'

 ShowCurrentDate=()=>{
 
  var date = new Date().getDate();
  var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return year + ',' + month + ',' + date;
 }

const startDate = new Date(2020, 6, 7)
const todaysDate = new Date(2020, 7, 29)
var resultDays = differenceInDays(todaysDate, startDate)
var resultDaysToWeeks = (resultDays/7)
var resultWeeks = Math.trunc(resultDaysToWeeks);
var resultDaysLeft = (resultDays-(resultWeeks*7))

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#FF00FF', '#00FFFF']}
        style={styles.container}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.whiteText}>Pregnant</Text>
        <Text style={styles.number}>{resultWeeks}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.baseText}>weeks</Text>
        <Text style={styles.number}>{resultDaysLeft}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.baseText}>days</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  number: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 180,
    },
  baseText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 40,
      },
  whiteText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 60,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
})
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differenceInDays function accepts date type objects, whereas the return value of your showCurrentDate function is string type.
For today's date you can simply use:

```
var todaysdate = new Date()
```

Here is a working demo
https://codesandbox.io/live/o2zB0K

Comment: Hi, thanks. I got it make calculations but the answer it gives is wrong. Like in demo it gives only 23 days.... do I need to use date-fns format somehow? Thanks

Comment: It's not a problem with the format, you need to check for your timezone maybe. You can check for todaysdate value in the sandbox console.

Comment: It's something else. It's 31 days off, it can't be timezones problem. Take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-bush-r1680?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Got your point. So basically  JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. So in order to create date for 30th July 2019 you need to do new Date(2019,6,30)

Comment: Thank you  that works. 2 lessons I learned, with 'new Date()' I can get current date and time and javascripts count's 0 also in.